# jQuery variable not updating when dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

jQuery variables like following is working nicely when i reload page. But Once I change the data-agent_id attribute dynamically, after that "live" click not changing the "assigned_agent" variable as changed value. I have tried to declare the variable global still not working.

```
var assigned_agent = parseInt($(this).data('agent_id'));
```

Any help will highly appreciate.Thanks

Comment: Show us your click function.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. please share the complete relevant code(live event in your case).

Comment: You must be using `attr()` to change value. Show us how are you changing the `data_agent_id` attribute.

Comment: Thanks to all. Problem is solved  var assigned_agent = parseInt($(this).attr('data-agent_id'));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) isn't for accessing `data-*` attributes. `data` manages a cache of data associated with the element which is only **initialized** from `data-*` attributes when you first access it; after that, it's totally and completely disconnected from them.

To *interact* with `data-*` attributes, use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr), not `data`:

```
var assigned_agent = parseInt($(this).attr('data-agent_id')); // Or whatever the attribute name actually is
```

Alternately, of course, *always* use `data`, not `attr`, to both get and set, and understand that the attribute in the DOM will get out of sync with it.